# Pull names out of array and add line break after each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

Below is the unit test I wrote for a small piece of Ruby code.

```
subject { AutoShop.new 'Mr. Fix It', 'WA987654321', Employee.new('Sue', 'Owner', 0) }

it '#employee_list returns list of employee names' do
  # setup
  input = [Employee.new('Lou', 'Receptionist', 90_000)]
  subject.append_employees input
  subject.employee_list.should eq "Sue\nLou"
end
```

And here is the code for the class. However, I cannot get the names to display properly in the `employee_list` method. I'm brand new to Ruby, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
class AutoShop < Business

    attr_accessor :employees

  def initialize(name, tax_id, employee)
    super(name, tax_id)
    @employees = []
    @employees << employee
  end   

  def append_employees(input)
    input.map { |x| @employees << x  }  
  end

  def employee_list
    @employees.map {|x| x.name}
  end   

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `employee_list` method, based on your unit test, should output each name separated by a linebreak `\n`. So, add a `.join("\n")` to produce a string from the array.

```
def employee_list
  @employees.map {|x| x.name }.join("\n")
end
```

The `.map` can be done with a "pretzel-colon" shorthand too:

```
@employees.map(&:name).join("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Although @MichaelBerkowski already answered your main question, I would pay heed to your `append_employees` method looks a bit strange. You were likely to use `Array#each`, not `Array#map` there. While `@employees` variable is not affected by that change, the returning value differs (unnecessarily gorging your memory). Compare:

```
2.0.0-preview2 :001 > input = [1, 2, 3, 4]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4] 
2.0.0-preview2 :002 > e = [] ; input.each { |x| e << x  }
 => [1, 2, 3, 4] 
2.0.0-preview2 :003 > e = [] ; input.map { |x| e << x  }
 => [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```